# Fixing DOuble CApitals as I type

Tags: text-editing, text

I have a bit of a slow pinky. As my other fingers get faster and
faster at typing, my pinky just can't keep up. This frequently leads me to type sentences whose first word starts with two uppercase
letters. Here's a short example.

```
THere's nothing in there. DEfinitely not a body.
```

Usually what I do is hit `M-b M-c` (assuming I spot it immediately),
but I'm getting a little tired of that.

**How can I have Emacs fix this automatically for me?**

That is, I'd like Emacs to detect when I type a word that starts with
two uppercase letters followed by at least one lowercase letter, and
fix that automatically.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a function that will convert DOuble CApitals to Single Capitals.  I'd originally suggested adding it to `post-self-insert-hook`, but below is an option for a glorified minor mode so that you only add to that hook when you really want it:

```el
(defun dcaps-to-scaps ()
  "Convert word in DOuble CApitals to Single Capitals."
  (interactive)
  (and (= ?w (char-syntax (char-before)))
       (save-excursion
         (let ((end (point)))
           (and (if (called-interactively-p)
                    (skip-syntax-backward "w")
                  (= -3 (skip-syntax-backward "w")))
                (let (case-fold-search)
                  (looking-at "\\b[[:upper:]]\\{2\\}[[:lower:]]"))
                (capitalize-region (point) end))))))
(add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'dcaps-to-scaps nil 'local)
```

And the minor mode definition:

```el
(define-minor-mode dubcaps-mode
  "Toggle `dubcaps-mode'.  Converts words in DOuble CApitals to
Single Capitals as you type."
  :init-value nil
  :lighter (" DC")
  (if dubcaps-mode
      (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'dcaps-to-scaps nil 'local)
    (remove-hook 'post-self-insert-hook #'dcaps-to-scaps 'local)))
```

For what it's worth, using this version:

- is simple: just turn it on/off manually or in a mode hook;
- requires no changes to key bindings, so you're not losing any other functionality.

Even when you add it to `post-self-insert-hook`, the overhead is almost non-existent, at least according to some simple benchmarking.  On my machine, here's what I get with 10,000 repetitions each of a ludicrously simple form and the `dcaps-to-scaps` function:

```
(benchmark-run-compiled 10000 (+ 1 1))          ; => .001 to .003 -ish
(benchmark-run-compiled 10000 (dcaps-to-scaps)) ; => .003 to .006 -ish
```

So, yes, it's slower than adding 1 + 1, but in absolute terms you'll never notice.

Comment: You could use `looking-at-p`, which does not set the match data at all (that's ok since you don't need or use it here).

Comment: A few more remarks, mostly unimportant (but I prefer your answer so I want to contribute ;p) : the use of `forward-word` won't work well with `subword-mode`, using `(char-syntax (char-before))` will (I guess) ignore any syntax class set with properties (alternate solution: `(syntax-after (1- (point))`), and (last but not least) the regexp won't find accented letters (e.g. "ÉMincer", in french)

Comment: @YoungFrog: updated to deal with the `forward-word` issue, and changed the regexp to deal with accented capitals.

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer `and` over `when`, in particular in the first instance?

Comment: @Clément: `and` is short-circuited, so the logic works like `when` here.  I'm not sure if there are best practices about using one versus the other, but it seems like it would make a good question on this site (I'd upvote, anyway).

Comment: Done: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14195/and-vs-when-for-conditionals

Comment: @Dan Have you considered contributing this to Emacs itself? Seems useful to have in the core, or at least in ELPA if the devs don't want it in core for some reason.

Comment: There is another bug regarding `subword-mode`. To fix it, `(capitalize-word 1)` needs to be replaced with `(capitalize-region (point) end)`. Also an additional variable `end` which stores the end of the word needs to be introduced into the function. Otherwise it is a nice solution!

Answer (score 8):

My preference is to simply create a new function that does what the usual `self-insert-command` would do plus **more**.

Here are few reasons:

- Finer control on which major modes should have this auto-correcting capability. For this use case, it could be text-only modes like `org-mode`, `text-mode`, etc.
- For the type of correction requested in the question, user would typically hit `SPC` or `RET` or `.` key after the word. So using something like `post-self-insert-hook` might be an overkill, and we would do that extra processing each time we hit any key.

So the below proposed solution binds this function with just the `SPC` key in `org-mode-map` (ignoring the corner case where the word could be the last word in a line). If needed, the user can bind similar wrapper functions to more keys.

```el
(defun space-plus-more ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (backward-word 1)
    (let ((case-fold-search))
      (when (looking-at-p "[A-Z]\\{2\\}.*?[a-z]+.*?\\b")
        (capitalize-word 1))))
  (self-insert-command 1))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<SPC>") #'space-plus-more)
```

---

This is an interesting elisp exercise :)

*I personally wouldn't want to bind this to `RET` as then I would lose the default bindings in `org-mode` and probably other major modes too.* But it was interesting to learn about `elt` and `this-command-keys-vector`.

```el
(defun my/fix-double-caps ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (backward-word 1)
    (let ((case-fold-search))
      (when (looking-at-p "[A-Z]\\{2\\}.*?[a-z]+.*?\\b")
        (capitalize-word 1))))
  (if (eq 13 (elt (this-command-keys-vector) 0)) ; detect RET
      (newline)
    (self-insert-command 1)))

(let ((maps-list (list org-mode-map
                       text-mode-map))
      (keys-list (list "<SPC>" "<RET>" ".")))
  (dolist (map maps-list)
    (dolist (key keys-list)
      (define-key map (kbd key) #'my/fix-double-caps))))
```

Comment: Oh yes, restricting it to text-derived modes is definitely a good idea. :)

Comment: @Malabarba don't you want this behaviour in strings for modes derived from prog-mode ?

Comment: @YoungFrog sure, but then it would have to check that it's actually inside a string, otherwise it would just get in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer does not provide solution that you're expecting
(interactive correction of words as you type), I would like to share my ways
to fight such problems.

First of all, I don't like things that silently change my text (capitalize,
etc., what if you want to type the word `IBuffer`, I think such "corrector"
is a wrong way), so I advise two things:

First, try to enable feature "Sticky Keys". It may seem weird at first but I
use it all the time. This feature is available on OS/desktop environment
level, it's not Emacs stuff. When this thing is enabled you first press
<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and then you press another key you want to
capitalize. This way your problem cannot even arise, only one letter is
capitalized in this sequential approach! It also reduces work your hands
need to do holding the <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key. I think it's easier to type
now.

Second, now you still can use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> key normally (holding it)
when your think it's necessary, but I would like to propose you an Emacs
package called [Fix Word](https://github.com/mrkkrp/fix-word). Even if you don't like
"Sticky Keys", you can correct words into their proper forms easily, and you
can correct several words in a row without useless movements of the
cursor. Give it a try, I use it all the time. (It's still difficult to correct things if you entered several words and the word you need to capitalize is somewhere in the middle.)