# "and" vs "when" for conditionals

Tags: elisp-macros, conditionals

This is a follow-up on the comments on [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13975/2429). The following bits of code seem to be equivalent:

`(and a b)`

`(when a b)`

Of course `and` lets you put more conditions: `(and a b c d)` means `(when (and a b c) d)`

I tend to use `when` only to express branching. Are there actual differences? Is it better to use one or the other?

I don't have Emacs' C source at hand; `and` is a C function; `when` is a macro that expands to `if`, which itself is a C function.

Comment: "Of course and lets" should be "Of course \`and\` lets", but that's only a 2 character change and isn't an allowed edit. There's no override.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**TL;DR:** `when` is about side effects, `and` is for pure boolean expressions.

As you've noticed, `and` and `when` differ only in syntax, but are otherwise entirely equivalent.

The syntactic difference is quite important, though: `when` wraps an implicit `progn` around all but the first argument forms.  `progn` is an inherently imperative feature:  It evaluates all but the very last body form for their side effects only, discarding whatever value they returned.

As such, `when` is an imperative form as well: It's main purpose is to wrap side-effecting forms, because only the value of the very last form actually matters for the body.

`and` on the other hand is a pure function, whose main purpose is to look at the return values of the given argument forms:  Unless you explicitly wrap `progn` around any of its arguments, the value of every argument form is important, and no value is ever ignored.

Hence, the real difference between `and` and `when` is stylistic:  You use `and` for pure boolean expressions, and `when` to put a guard around side-effecting forms.

Hence, these are bad style:

```
;; `when' used for a pure boolean expression
(let ((use-buffer (when (buffer-live-p buffer)
                    (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name buffer)))))
  ...)

;; `and' used as guard around a side-effecting form
(and (buffer-file-name buffer) (write-region nil nil (buffer-file-name buffer)))
```

And these are good:

```
(let ((use-buffer (and (buffer-live-p buffer)
                       (file-exists-p (buffer-file-name buffer)))))
  ...)

(when (buffer-file-name buffer)
 (write-region nil nil (buffer-file-name buffer)))
```

---

I know that some people disagree about this, and happily use `and` to guard side-effects, but I think that this is really bad style.  We have these different forms for a reason:  Syntax *matters*.  If it didn't, we'd all only ever use `if`, which is the only conditional form you really need in Emacs Lisp semantically.  All other boolean and conditional forms can be written in terms of `if`.

Comment: +1; I tend to agree with the stylistic argument. I'll wait to see if someone comes up with another explanation before accepting.

Comment: Forgive this sarcastic remark, but `and` beeing a pure function reminds me of people having reinterpreted the bible at various times to coincide with the norms of the day.

Comment: IMO (i.e., in the style I use), `and` is about *caring about the return value*. It is not necessarily not about using side effects. If my program cares about the return value then I use `and`. If it does not then I use `when`. IOW, I use `when` *only* for side effects, but I might well use a `progn` in one of the args to `and`. It's about whether the return value matters, not about whether it *alone* matters.

Comment: Your boolean vs. imperative difference is the key. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: `and` is not a function in any Lisp I know of. In Emacs Lisp it's a special form, in Common Lisp it's a macro, simply because it's expected to have short-circuit behavior (impossible to achieve with functions, because they always evaluate their arguments).

Comment: @Mark While technically correct, does this have any relevance to the stylistic difference between `and` and `when`?  If you think so—I don't—please feel free to edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @lunaryorn, Yes, it's not really relevant, but it's true, so I think it's incorrect to write that `and` is a function, when it's not. It doesn't matter how relevant the fact is to the question, we should always use correct terms, that's all.

Comment: @Mark is right, and then slightly wrong where he backs off too much from his initial right. It is incorrect to say that `and` never ignores an argument. In fact, if the first argument to `and` evaluates to `nil`, the remaining arguments are not evaluated. This is important in usages where evaluating those arguments could lead to errors or lengthy computations. Example idiom: `(and (boundp 'foo) foo)`.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I wrote about the _value_ of an argument, that is, _after_ evaluation, not the argument itself.

Comment: Well, I don't think “the value of every argument form is important” is consistent with what that interpretation. It could have been better expressed by saying that no form is evaluated only to have its value thrown away.

Comment: Somewhat OT, but: The difference is more than stylistic in Lisps that don't pun `nil` to mean all of "false", "the empty list", "void", etc. For example in Scheme and Racket the non-truthy result of `when` is `void` (i.e. "no meaning") whereas for `and` it is `#f` ("false"). Although this is N/A for Elisp, it's something a Lisp generalist might consider.

Answer (score 6):

Let me start off by saying that `(and a b)` and `(when a b)` in your example do the same thing: First `a` is evaluated. `b` is evaluated if `a` is *true*<sup>#</sup>.

**But** `and` and `when` are used for different things.

- You would use `(and a b)` to return *true*<sup>#</sup> if BOTH `a` and `b` are *true*<sup>#</sup> (or non-nil); and `nil` otherwise.
- You would use `(when a b)` or to be more correct,

  ```el
  (when a
     ;; do something like b
     )
  ```

  when you want the "b" code to execute if and only if `a` is *true*<sup>#</sup>.

---

Here is an example where you use `when` and `and` together:

```el
(when (and a b)
   (do-c))
```

Above, the function `do-c` is called ONLY if BOTH `a` and `b` are *true*<sup>#</sup>.

---

### References for study

- [Elisp - Conditionals](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html) *(look for the `when` section in here)*
- [Elisp - Combining Conditions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Combining-Conditions.html) *(look for the `and` section in here)*

<sub># **All references to *true* refer to the Boolean TRUE.**</sub>

Comment: `and` doesn't return `t` if all its arguments are non-nil, but the value of the last argument.

Comment: By `t`, I meant the Boolean TRUE or non-nil. Thanks, I will clarify that in my answer.

Comment: I don't think your answer goes much further that what I already stated in the question; I know what both do, and the final example you give already appears in my question (`(when (and a b) c)`). In addition, the part about how `and` and `when` suggests that that's actually how they are used in general, but the very basis for this question was the fact that I often see them used differently (see for example the answer I linked to in my question).

Comment: From a purely functional construct point-of-view, **when** is for non-terminating evaluations and **and** is for direct symbols and boolean logic. Functional programming needs this distinction; imperative programming fudge this away.

Comment: @Clément I tried to emphasize that even though `and` and `when` give the same result, we generally use `and` when you need a form to return nil or non-nil boolean status and `when` for conditionals. Also note the difference in the style of how they are generally written, where to new line, where to indent,.. in order to convey a clear distinctions in what those constructs convey. In summary: stylistic.

Comment: Emacs User: Can you clarify? I don't really see what functionality has to do here. Do you mean purity?

Comment: I don't think "boolean true" is more clear than just "true".

Answer (score 1):

@Tarsius's answer is almost right, but not quite.

The convention is that the ***return value*** of `and` and `or` ***matters***. When you see `and` or `or` in code that follows the convention then this is a signal that their return value is used.

That does *not* mean that they are or they need to be pure functions (perform no side effects). Any of their steps (sexps) *can perform side effects*.

It's just that the return values of their constituent sexps matter, in these two ways:

- The return value of each sexp other than the last determines *whether subsequent sexps are evaluated*. In this regard only whether the value is `nil` or non-`nil` matters.
- The return value any of the sexps *can be the return value of the entire `and` or `or`*, and that value matters (to surrounding code). It need not be Boolean `nil` or `t`, and it need not be handled by the surrounding code as a Lisp Boolean value (`nil` or non-`nil`). It can be *anything at all*.

What's important is only that when you see `and` or `or` then you can expect that the return value is used somewhere; nothing more.