# How to match only a word when using `re-search-backward` function

Tags: search, words

I want to replace a character inside a word, so I wrote:

```
(setq regexp "[ab]")
(and (re-search-backward regexp nil t 1)
     (replace-match "c"))
```

This replaces `a` or `b` to `c` as I wish, but I want to set a bound of it.
There is a `BOUND` option with `re-search-backward`.
How can I make the match only a word that is under the current cursor?

Thanks for @jackson I can write the function, but still it doesn't work properly.

```
(setq regexp ".*[ab].*")
(defun test-it ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region (progn (backward-word) (point))
                        (progn (forward-word) (point)))
      (and (re-search-backward regexp)
           (replace-match "c")))))
```

Thins function replaces `ab` to `ac` and `ad` to `cd` as I expected, but it doesn't replace `ac` to `cc`. Why?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you implement some sort of auto-correction here?

Comment: I want make a pinyin (Chinese tone mark) input mode. like `ma -> mǎ`. So I want to replace `aāáà` to `ǎ` by a function. I can write it separatey by using `("a" "ǎ") ("ā" "ǎ") ("á" "ǎ") ("à" "ǎ")`. But I thought it is a bit redundant.

Comment: *Yay, finally a chinese introduction lesson I took years ago helps me tell that this has something to do with mother and horse :)* I don't understand or type in Chinese, but have you looked at `set-input-method` and `toggle-input-method`?

Comment: Also, is this for an occcasional phonetics correction? If not, you can probably modify the [solution here for fixing double caps](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13975/115) to always "autocorrect" based on custom rules like `ma*` to `mǎ`, `ma-` to `mā`, ``ma` `` to `mà`, and so on.

Comment: As far as I know these two method are intended someone who can type Chinese, right? I want to make a minor mode for the phonetics notation.

Comment: Thanks for introducing `double-caps-mode`, but it's a bit different I want to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're asking.  If you're using `re-search-backward` because you want to include the beginning of the word that encompasses the point, perhaps this does what you want:

```
(setq regexp ".*[ab].*")
(defun test-it ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region (progn (backward-word 1) (point))
                        (progn (forward-word 1) (point)))
      (backward-word 1)
      (if (looking-at regexp)
          (replace-match "frog")))))
```

The code is a bit clumsy, but will replace the regexp with the given string if it matches.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed your code a little because I want to search the string backward from the `(point)`. But my code have still a problem, it would be very nice if you can take a glance at it.

Comment: I changed the regexp to be `.*[ab].*` - you probably don't want the `.*` - I did because I was checking to see if the entire word would be replaced.  You're just replacing a single character.